# ransack with simple_form builder input_html option

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, ransack

I am using ransack (1.5.1) with  simple_form (3.1.0)

I use the following search form

```
<%= search_form_for @search, :builder => SimpleForm::FormBuilder do |f| %>
```

and the following input_field

```
<%= f.input_field(:contact_groups_name_eq_any, input_html: { class: 'inline tight' },
                                    collection: @contact_group_names, as: :check_boxes) %>
```

I get the following output:

```
<div class="checkbox"><input checked="checked" class="check_boxes required" id="q_contact_groups_name_eq_any_family" input_html="{:class=>&quot;inline tight&quot;}" name="q[contact_groups_name_eq_any][]" value="Family" type="checkbox"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="q_contact_groups_name_eq_any_family">Family</label></div>
```

Why isn't the input_html: hash updating the input class?

Comment: Is it not just `f.input(..., input_html: { class: "things" })`